# How can I identify consecutive occurrences of a specific value in an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, evaluation

I need to evaluate whether an array has two consecutive occurrences of a specific value.  For example, I want to evaluate whether an array has two instances of the value '1' in consecutive index positions.  I only want this to evaluate to 'true' for repetitions of the value '1' (i.e., not for other repeated values) and only for repetitions at consecutive index positions.  I've found many vaguely analogous questions and solutions, but nothing matching this specific circumstance.  Specific examples below:

```
    [0,1,1,0,2,0]  // Evaluates to True Because of Two Consecutive 1's
    [0,1,0,1,2,2]  // Evaluates to False, In Spite of Repeated 2's and Multiple (Non-Consecutive) Instances of 1
```

Comment: What about a simple `for` loop comparing current and previous (or next) value? Why is this so special that you haven't even tried that simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Returns true if the array contains two consecutive instances of the given value.
func checkForConsecutiveValue(value: Int, within numberArray: [Int]) -> Bool {
  
  // Iterate through each element of the array (not including the last one),
  // and check if the element after is the same, and that both are the specific value.
  for index in numberArray.indices.dropLast() {
    if numberArray[index] == value && numberArray[index + 1] == value {
      return true
    }
  }
  
  // If it doesn't find the given value consecutively
  return false
}
```

To use:

```
let specificValue: Int = 1
let numberArray: [Int] = [0,1,1,0,2,0]
let hasConsecutiveValue = checkForConsecutiveValue(value: specificValue, within: numberArray)
```

Comment: this would unnecessarily iterate the whole collection

Comment: There, I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: This would crash if there is a single value at the last index of the collection

Comment: Whoops I should have had numberArray.count - 1. Now it works correctly. thanks

Comment: Now it should probably crash on empty array.

Comment: @gcharita kkkk we are giving him a hard time. He is at least showing some effort

Comment: @Eric33187 `for index in numberArray.indices.dropLast() {`

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, it's nice thought I didn't thought to use indexes in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you Leo. lol. I added a guard statement. EVERYONE HAPPY NOW? hahahaha

Comment: @Eric33187 no need to use guard check my previous comment

Comment: Okay you're right. Can't people edit it? I'm new to stack so not sure how editing works really.

Comment: If the user has that privilege (enough reputation) yes. But it is better if you edit your own post

Comment: Okay makes sense. Thanks for the tip. And thanks for all the pointers everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a for loop. I made a little extension in `Sequence` protocol for the solution to be more generic:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {
    func consecutiveOccurrences(of element: Element) -> Bool {
        var appeared = false
        for item in self {
            if item == element, appeared {
                return true
            } else if item == element {
                appeared = true
            } else {
                appeared = false
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

print([0,1,1,0,2,0].consecutiveOccurrences(of: 1)) // true
print([0,1,0,1,2,2].consecutiveOccurrences(of: 1)) // false
```